# Backing up Event Scheduler

Tags: php, mysql, events

I had just backed up mysql database but my Event Schedulers are gone. How do I back them up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

man mysqldump:

```
  ·   --events, -E
      Include Event Scheduler events for the dumped databases in the output.
```

Comment: Is there a way to actually view the code in an event after it has been added?